# RadioButton Issue get checked when sending?

Tags: android, android-button, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

Having two RadioButtons and button send.
When I click on the send button the 2 RadioButtons are checked.

How to avoid this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KO3t.png)

Comment: add the radio buttons inside `radiogroup`

Comment: I have radio group in the xml but i draw the radio buttons with the java code

Comment: i see your method in that class i have a button the send request when it finish there is dialog appear when that dialog appear the radio buttons set all checked

Comment: i draw the radio button into java code. i upload image that show the issue see the radio buttons the two radio buttons are checked how to avoid this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the radio buttons so inside the xml add the radio buttons inside this tag:

```
<RadioGroup> .....</RadioGroup>
```

then in your activity do this:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup); //declare the radiogroup


radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            // find which radio button is selected

            if(checkedId == R.id.radiobtn1) {

                //code here
            } else if(checkedId == R.id.radiobtn2) {

                //code here

            } else {

               //code here
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one `RadioButton` to be checked at once, keep them inside a `RadioGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

Just Put your RadioButtons inside RadioGroup